# Modified date changed after google drive API copy command

Tags: android, google-drive-api

An Android app I'm developing integrates with Google Drive. I have a feature to copy a file on the drive and I use the following code:

```
        File newFile = new File();
        newFile.setTitle(mItem.GetName());
        ParentReference newParent = new ParentReference();
        newParent.setId(gDriveFolder.getFileId());
        List<ParentReference> parents = new ArrayList<ParentReference>(1);
        parents.add(newParent);
        newFile.setParents(parents);
        File copiedFile = service.files().copy(mItem.getFileId(), newFile).execute();   
        String copiedFileId = copiedFile.getId();

        long copiedModDate = copiedFile.getModifiedDate().getValue();       
        Log.d("serverSideCopyMove", "File returned from copy command has modified date of " + copiedModDate);

        // bug here in google drive because the last mod date returned from the above 
        // gets changed a few micro-seconds later, thus the need to make a separate
        // server call to get new mod date again
        File getFile = service.files().get(copiedFileId).execute();
        copiedModDate = getFile.getModifiedDate().getValue(); //why different value?
        Log.d("serverSideCopyMove", "Separate call to get same copied file returns modified date of " + copiedModDate);
        // end of workaround
```

You will see from my code that the modified date of the file returned from the copy command is different to when I perform a 'get' on the same file. I was just wondering if this was a bug or am I using the calls incorrectly?

Comment: This is unexpected. I'm not able to reproduce the problem on the other hand :(

Comment: Thanks for checking. I've just noticed I'm using google-api-services-drive-v2-rev68-1.13.2-beta.jar and there is a new revision. I'll update the jars and try again.